# Habilitar e desabilitar campos clicando no checked

Tags: javascript

Colegas.

Tenho um campo do qual preciso habilitar e desabilitar ao clicar em um checked. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico no checked, consigo desabilitar, mas quando desmarco, o campo continua desabilitado. Estou fazendo dessa forma:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function desabilitar(valor){
      if(valor == 'sim'){
       document.getElementById('tel').disabled = true;
     }else{
        document.getElementById('tel').disabled = false;
     }
    }
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="NomeEscola" style="font-weight: normal">Telefone Residencial: 
<input type="checkbox" onclick="desabilitar('sim')"> O mesmo do aluno</label>
<div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #FAFAFA">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TelefoneResidencial" id="tel" data-inputmask="'alias': '(99)9999-9999'" maxlength="150">
</div>
```

Comment: O problema é que no clique do checkbox você sempre passa como "sim". onclick="desabilitar('sim')". Independente se ele está marcado ou não, sempre será sim e desabilitará. Faça a verificação se o campo está disabled, se sim, você desmarca, do contrário marca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloquei um exemplo abaixo do seu código com a lógica correta. Desta forma funciona como deseja.

> O problema é que no clique do `checkbox` você sempre passa como "sim". `onclick="desabilitar('sim')`. Independente se ele está marcado ou não, sempre será sim e desabilitará. Faça a verificação se o campo está disabled, se sim, você desmarca, do contrário marca.

```js
function desabilitar(valor) {
  var status = document.getElementById('tel').disabled;

  if (valor == 'sim' && !status) {
    document.getElementById('tel').disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('tel').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="NomeEscola" style="font-weight: normal">Telefone Residencial: 
<input type="checkbox" onclick="desabilitar('sim')"> O mesmo do aluno</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #FAFAFA">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TelefoneResidencial" id="tel" data-inputmask="'alias': '(99)9999-9999'" maxlength="150">
  </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Bruno.

Answer (score 1):

Tens de usar o `.checked` dessa checkbox para o efeito que queres.  Passar só o `sim` nunca permite o estado "não".

**Sugestão:**

HTML:

```
onclick="desabilitar(this.checked)"
```

JavaScript:

```
function desabilitar(selecionado) {
    document.getElementById('tel').disabled = selecionado;
}
```

**Exemplo a funcionar:**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="NomeEscola" style="font-weight: normal">Telefone Residencial: 
<input type="checkbox" onclick="desabilitar(this.checked)"/> O mesmo do aluno</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #FAFAFA">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TelefoneResidencial" id="tel" data-inputmask="'alias': '(99)9999-9999'" maxlength="150" />
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function desabilitar(selecionado) {
    document.getElementById('tel').disabled = selecionado;
  }
</script>
```